# Date is shown twice if setMaxDate is used on DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

When setting the maximum date on a date picker dialog like this:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

The date is shown normally, but also a second time at the top of the dialog. I've seen that many people have encountered this bug but I didn't find a solution.

[image]

You can also see it on [this image from another user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8fvJ.jpg)

**Is there any way to prevent or solve this, besides using reflection?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the bug by calling `dialog.setTitle(null)` every time a maximum date is set.

I posted this issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/72284741